# Can we prove using pumping lemma that language F = {$a^ i b ^j c ^k$ | i, j, k ≥ 0 and if i = 1 then j = k} is not regular?

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I am currently solving a problem in which we have to show that we can not prove using pumping lemma that the language mentioned in the question is not regular.Here is the full question

> Consider the language F = {$a^i b^j c^k$ | i, j, k ≥ 0 and if i = 1 then
> j = k}.
>
> a. Show that F is not regular.
>
> b. Show that F acts like a regular language in the pumping lemma. In other        words, give a pumping length p and demonstrate that F satisfies the three conditions of the pumping lemma for this value of p.
>
> c. Explain why parts (a) and (b) do not contradict the pumping lemma.

But, I am able to prove it using pumping lemma that language is not regular. For that I take:

> pumping length as 3
>
> x:a ; y:b ; z:c
>
> $xy^lz$ ∈ F for l = 1
>
> $xy^lz$ ∉ F for l > 1

Is there some problem with the above shown proof or the question is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

> For that I take:
>
> x:a ; y:b ; z:c

You can't do that. You have to first give a pumping length $p$ and then you have to show that there is *no* decomposition of the word $abc$ into $xyz$ with $|y|\ge 1$ and $|xy| \le p$ for which $xy^n z \in F$. If we take your word $abc$ and decompose as $x=\varepsilon$, $y = a$, $z=bc$ then the pumped words are $a^nbc$ and are all in $F$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have taken pumping length as 3. Now, I have added it to the question. So, in this case is the proof correct.

Comment: You haven't understood my point: the proof strategy is completely flawed because showing the *existence* of a decomposition which *can't* be pumped is not the same as showing the *non-existence* of a decomposition which *can* be pumped.

Comment: So, if ,even a single decomposition exists for which pumping lemma holds true then language is said to be regular?

Comment: The answer to that question is implicit in part (c) of your original problem.